# Kotlinic pattern for using Spring Data JPA's "query by example"

Tags: spring-data-jpa, kotlin

Spring Data JPA introduces a nice feature, ["query by example" (QBE)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example). You express your search criteria by *constructing an instance of the entity*.

You do not have to write JPQL. It uses less "magic" than does [repository query derivation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation). The syntax is nice. It prevents explosions of trivial repository code. It survives refactors very well.

There's a problem though: QBE only works if you can *partially construct* an object.

Here's my entity:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
data class Product(
        @Id val id: String,
        val city: String,
        val shopName: String,
        val productName: String,
        val productVersion: Short
)
```

Here's my repository (empty! this is a nice thing about QBE):

```kotlin
@Repository
interface ProductRepository : JpaRepository<Product, String>
```

And here's how you would fetch a `List<Product>` — all the products that are sold in some shop, in some city:

```kotlin
productRepository.findAll(Example.of(Product(city = "London", shopName="OkayTea")))
```

Or at least, that's what I *want* to do. There's a problem. It's **not possible** to construct this object:

```kotlin
Product(city = "London", shopName="OkayTea")
```

This is because `Product`'s constructor requires that *all* its fields be defined. And indeed: that's what I want most of the time.

The usual compromise in Java would be: construct entities using no-args constructor, make everything mutable, have no guarantees about completedness.

Is there a nice Kotlin pattern to solve this problem:

- *generally* require that all args are instantiated on construction
- provide **also** some mechanism to produce partially-constructed instances for use with Example API

Admittedly these look like totally conflicting goals. But maybe there's another way to approach this?

For example: maybe we can make a mock/proxy object, which appears to be a Product, but doesn't have the same construction constraints?

Comment: Not possible with data classes, if you want to keep all the nice things that data classes give you.

Answer (score 5):

You can query by example using kotlin data classes with non-null fields, however it will not look as good as java code.

```
val matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
    .withMatcher("city", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatcher().exact())
    .withMatcher("shopName", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatcher().exact())
    .withIgnorePaths("id", "productName", "productVersion")

val product = Product(
    id = "",
    city = "London",
    shopName = "OkayTea",
    productName = "",
    productVersion = 0
)

productRepository.findAll(Example.of(product, matcher))
```

If you are using it for integration tests and you don't want to pollute your `Repository` interface with methods which are only used in said tests and also 
you have a lot of fields in the database entity class, you can create an extension function that extracts fields which will be ignored in the query.

```
private fun <T : Any> KClass<T>.ignoredProperties(vararg exclusions: String): Array<String> {
    return declaredMemberProperties
        .filterNot { exclusions.contains(it.name) }
        .map { it.name }
        .toTypedArray()
}
```

and use it like this:

```
val ignoredFields = Product::class.ignoredProperties("city", "shopName")

val matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
    .withMatcher("city", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatcher().exact())
    .withMatcher("shopName", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatcher().exact())
    .withIgnorePaths(*ignoredFields)
```

Comment: In my project, I want to ignore if null. For example, if shopName is null, then it will ignore this condition. How can I handle this case?

Answer (score -1):

because the parameters on the primary constructor is not optional and not nullable. you can makes parameters nullable and set a default value `null` for each, for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
data class Product(
        @Id val id: String? = null,
        val city: String? = null,
        val shopName: String? = null,
        val productName: String? = null,
        val productVersion: Short? = null
)
```

However, you must operates `Product` properties with safe-call `?.`, for example:

```
val product = Product()

//                   safe-call ---v
val cityToLowerCase = product.city?.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: thanks; so we discard all completedness guarantees. but this is a big compromise: we significantly change our completedness contract, solely to support QBE. I was thinking maybe there's another way — using mocks or proxies, for example — to produce a `Product` instance. Mocks/proxies would fulfil the Example API's requirement, and would _not_ have the constructor constraints of the Product class.

Comment: @Birchlabs Hi, if your column in database can't be nullable. the column should be has a default value. you can using a default value to initializing the property on primary constructor.e.g: `val id:Int, val city:String="unknown"` and go on. the `id` is **required** and the `city` is **optional**. and my answer just is an opinion, let you know there is a feature in kotlin.

Comment: I'm not worried about database constraints. If I want to enforce "never persist null", I can do that with `@NotNull` persistence annotation. The bigger problem is that I want to prevent developers of my application from constructing invalid instances. The constructor used to give me a guarantee that every `Product` instance in my application had all of its fields initialized in a valid way. Whereas this constructor removes that guarantee, in order to support QBE.

Comment: Expressing the constraint `id` is **required** is complex; it can be required at construction-time, at API boundary, at persistence boundary. In particular: `id` is **required** at persistence boundary, but **optional** in a query. Ideally, QBE should have a different set of constraints to other use-cases.

Comment: @Birchlabs well. if you want to make sure every properties is not null. the QBE don't appropriate for you in this case, sir. since you must be provide all properties. let's see you can set properties via setter. but unset properties is `null`.

Comment: @Birchlabs sir, as you said you keep the constraints via `@NotNull` rather than kotlin non-nullable properties. so I think there is no problem. and every reference type can be nullable  in java. if you mark all properties non-nullable on primary constructor, you can't instantiate without given all of the properties. in short, you shouldn't adding database constraints on language level. instead, you should using `@NotNull` , `@Unique` and .etc.

Comment: While it *is* a solution, it does not answer the question. @Birchlabs explicitly says it should "generally require that all args are instantiated on construction" and even recognizes this solution in his question, deeming it undesirable.

Comment: @Pete hi, sir. but I think he can't  instantiate the `Product` without give all non-nullable properties in kotlin. it can be done in java since the reference type can be nullable.

Comment: @holi-java Yes, that is true, but that does not make that your answer actually *answers the question*. "It is not possible" is a perfectly valid answer, though.

Comment: @Pete I agree with you. and I admit my answer is not a perfect one, but I think it is the only one solution for the OP operating QBE feature in spring-data module. since you can't pass `null` values into the primary constructor.  and as I mentioned preceding, if you want to using QBE you should separate database constraints from language level, and using jpa validation annotation instead.